# rpy2 installation errors

Tags: 14.04, apt, python-2.7, r

I am trying to install rpy2 but keep running into installation errors. I have found another post that had similar problems:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136523/rpy2-installation-error-os-linux-mint-17-r-3-1-2-python-2-7-6

Their solution was to install the following libraries:

- apt-get install libreadline-dev
- apt-get install r-base r-base-dev python-dev python-setuptools

I did that but I still have errors.

OS details:
Ubuntu 14.04
Python 2.7.6
R version 3.2.0

Installation errors:
https://bitbucket.org/snippets/foundryspatial/jkjAK

Any ideas?

Comment: Your output shows lots of warnings, but the only actual build error I noticed is `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llzma`: is the `liblzma-dev` package installed on your system?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you do not have lzma. Install it using this command

```
sudo apt install lzma-dev
```