# How to solve this rpy2 issue? I need rpy2 installed

Tags: python, r

I tried his; [rpy2 installation errors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/637259/rpy2-installation-errors) but it doesn't help either. 
I tried many! Please help!

```
Collecting rpy2
      Using cached rpy2-2.9.2.tar.gz
        Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
        rpy2 is no longer supporting Python < 3. Consider using an older rpy2 release when using an older Python release.

        ----------------------------------------
    Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-ivarJ9/rpy2/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never tried this package, but it seems that it [is packaged

for both Python2 and Python3](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=rpy2). You can try them by installing:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-rpy2 python-rpy2
```